# Looking for master/child table database on condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 2 tables:

```
DECLARE @MASTER TABLE (MAST_ID INT, 
                       MAST_NAME NVARCHAR(10), 
                       IS_ACTIVE CHAR(1)
                      )

INSERT INTO @MASTER 
VALUES (1, 'MAST1', 'A'), (2, 'MAST2', 'I'), 
       (3, 'MAST3', 'A'), (4, 'MAST4', 'A')

SELECT * FROM @MASTER

DECLARE @CHILD TABLE (CHD_ID INT, 
                      MAST_ID INT, 
                      CHD_NAME NVARCHAR(10), 
                      IS_ACTIVE CHAR(1)
                     )

INSERT INTO @CHILD 
VALUES (1, 1, 'CHD1', 'I'), (2, 2, 'CHD2', 'A'), 
       (3, 4, 'CHD3', 'A'), (4, 4, 'CHD4', 'I') 

SELECT * FROM @CHILD
```

1. I need all active master table data, which are active and for those there are active child data
2. I need all active child for above master data

Output should be like below

[image]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from @MASTER A where is_active = 'A' and 
exists (select 1 from @child where is_active = 'A' and mast_id = A.mast_id);
```

and

```
select * from @child A where is_active = 'A' and
exists (select 1 from @master where mast_id = A.mast_id and is_active = 'A');
```

Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a59c/4

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a subquery to obtain the `MAST_ID` from the `@CHILD` table where the `IS_ACTIVE = 'A'` and then subquery against the `@MASTER` to get `IS_ACTIVE = 'A'` for those `MAST_ID`

```
SELECT M.* 
FROM @MASTER M 
WHERE IS_ACTIVE = 'A' 
  AND MAST_ID IN (SELECT MAST_ID FROM @CHILD C WHERE IS_ACTIVE = 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered but for II part, you can use this query :

```
select c.*, m.MAST_NAME
from CHILD c inner join MASTER m
on c.MAST_ID=m.MAST_ID
where m.IS_ACTIVE='A' and c.IS_ACTIVE='A';
```